# What does "v1", "v2", "v3" and "v4" connections mean?

Tags: log

I'm an end user with poor understanding of networking and all. I decided to run a relay (ExitRelay 0 ;) ;) ) on a dedicated computer.

I simply want to know what those "v-something" connections mean when I have a look at my log. I'm talking about the line that looks like "Since startup, we have initiated [...] and received..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are versions on the OR protocol which are negotiated between the client and the relay upon connection.

From [`tor-spec.txt`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt):

```
2. Connections
...[SNIP]...
The initiator then sends a VERSIONS cell to the responder, which then
replies with a VERSIONS cell; they have then negotiated a Tor
protocol version.  Assuming that the version they negotiate is 3 or higher
(the only ones specified for use with this handshake right now), the
responder sends a CERTS cell, an AUTH_CHALLENGE cell, and a NETINFO
cell to the initiator, which may send either CERTS, AUTHENTICATE,
NETINFO if it wants to authenticate, or just NETINFO if it does not.
```

They have different cell packet layouts, changed as the protocol has been improved and expanded over time.

From [`tor-spec.txt`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt):

```
3. Cell Packet format

The basic unit of communication for onion routers and onion
proxies is a fixed-width "cell".

On a version 1 connection, each cell contains the following
fields:

    CircID                                [CIRCID_LEN bytes]
    Command                               [1 byte]
    Payload (padded with 0 bytes)         [PAYLOAD_LEN bytes]

On a version 2 or higher connection, all cells are as in version 1
connections, except for variable-length cells, whose format is:

    CircID                                [CIRCID_LEN octets]
    Command                               [1 octet]
    Length                                [2 octets; big-endian integer]
    Payload                               [Length bytes]

On a version 2 connection, variable-length cells are indicated by a
command byte equal to 7 ("VERSIONS").  On a version 3 or
higher connection, variable-length cells are indicated by a command
byte equal to 7 ("VERSIONS"), or greater than or equal to 128.

CIRCID_LEN is 2 for link protocol versions 1, 2, and 3.  CIRCID_LEN
is 4 for link protocol version 4 or higher.  The VERSIONS cell itself
always has CIRCID_LEN == 2 for backward compatibility.
```